# Launcher exe in nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm working on a win forms application that is modulized.
There's a base project that build the Executable and several solutions containing forms that add functionality to the program when it finds the dll.. The base project also contains a project that serves as a contract against the forms providing common functionality.
The base project and the form project are maintained by different teams and i'm looking for a good way to handle dependencies between them with nuget.

My idea is to have the base project produce a nuget package containing the contract and all files needed to start the program. This way a team working with a form could get all files to run and test their forms from nuget.
To add the contract nuget so it gets added as a reference is the easy part. The problem is .exe and additional dlls needed to start the program but not be added as references.

Alternatives i'm thinking about are
- a custom build step that copies the files from the nuget package dire tory to the output directory.
- adding them as contentFiles that copy to output dir.
- tools folder does not seam to work since it's only works in package manager console.

Looking for suggestions and comments

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom .NuSpec file, containing whatever contents you want inside of it. In the end, NuGet is just an archiving process, and you have a lot of freedom while working on it.

Also, I'm guessing that the usage of the exe files inside the package is done by writing command line strings? Rather than doing this, how about make an interface library, which provides exact functions to the users, and lets them call the exes using an API? This also makes error handling better.